# Anchor not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, anchor

I wanna make an anchor to `Branche 1`

In the page "die card" you can see a div (`Branchen`) with links. My problem is, if I click the link `Branche 1` it's not going to the div `Branche 1`, any advice ?

[Here a js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFhq7/)

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="content" id="branchen" name="branche">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <a href="#menupanel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" data-corners="true" data-wrapperels="span"  title="Menu"></a>
        <h1>Branchen</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="Branche">
        <p><a href="#b1">Branche 1</a></p>
        <p><a href="branche2" >Branche 2</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Branche 3</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Branche 4</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Branche 5</a></p>
        <p><a href="#">Branche 6</a></p>
    </div>

    <div  id="branche1" name="b1">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
                <a href="#menupanel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" data-corners="true" data-wrapperels="span"  title="Menu"></a>
                <h1>Branche 1</h1>
        </div>
                <img src="bilder/branche1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>

    <!-- Other branches -->

</div>
```

Comment: @Leonardo20 If the answer is correct accept the answer it help for otheres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor link (`#b1`) must match `id`, not `name`.

But your issue come also from jQuery mobile. To make anchor works, you need to specify `data-ajax="false"` on your anchor link :

```
<a href="#branche1" data-ajax="false">Branche 1</a>

<div id="branche1">
    ...
</div>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/xFhq7/3/)
[jQuery mobile reference](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Comment: See my edit, you need to add `data-ajax="false"` on your links.

Comment: a little question, but how it works, if i click on page "home", in the listview of branchen ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is this "page home" link ?

Comment: the page "Einstieg", if i click on "branchen" in the listview on page "die card" it works but not work in the page "Einstieg"

Comment: `#branche` is inside `#card`, you won't be able to jump to it without showing `#card` page before. This is another problem, far more complex.

Comment: Hummm, are you sure to understand what is ajax made for ?